# Can Selenium click only the visible element, if the xpath returns 2 WebElements

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a responsive design, so many items I need to interact with have 2 WebElements. One for Desktop and one for Mobile, and I am trying to use PageFactory. Here's what I have now to identify and interact with the element.

```
//this returns 2 webelements, one for desktop and one for mobile
    @FindBy(xpath = "//selector-dropdown/p")
    private WebElement dropdown;

    public void ClickDropdown() throws InterruptedException {       
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(dropdown)).click();

    }
```

I was under the impression that `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(WebElement)` would find the first element visible. Right now when I open the app on Desktop, it finds the element (Desktop is first in the DOM). But on Mobile, it times out waiting for visibility, because it is stuck waiting for the first one to become visible.

My alternative is using @FindBy to declare every element twice, and  making an if statement to decide which path to take. Is this extra work the only way to make it work?

Comment: These issues might be exposing an opportunity to do some refactoring to have your architecture determine and use a specific selector based on it being mobile or something else. It would take some work to get setup, but will make maintenance so much easier moving forward. If statements work but there might be some friendlier design patterns you can use for this.

Comment: As it is, I can uniquely identify them easily enough. But that is extra work, declaring every WebElement for mobile and desktop, and essentially writing each method twice. Maybe my idea isn't the solution for all scenarios, but to me it seems easier to use an xpath that hits 2 elements, and run the test on whichever one is visible.

Comment: In a DOM i don't think 2 elements can have same absolute xpath; but relative can be same at times, so you can try distinguishing between the 2 elements by including previous elements in identification (if possible sahre the HTML)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining @Andersons and @SiKing answers into a solution that can be used everywhere, you could make a method available to all of your `PageObjects` in a base class, which you might already have:

```
protected WebElement getVisibleElement(List<WebElement> elements)
{
    //Need a guard clause here to ensure there are exactly two elements,
    //Or make the wait check for all elements more safely. Either way,
    //consider changing the method name to be clear about expectations

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    wait.until(
        ExpectedConditions.or(
             //This should be done more safely, unless already guarded to expect 2 elements
             ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(elements.get(0))),
             ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(elements.get(1)))
        )
    );

    for (WebElement element : elements) {
        if (element.isDisplayed())
        {
            return element;
        }
    }
    //Throw element not visible exception or something
}
```

Then in your PageObject:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//selector-dropdown/p")
private List<WebElement> dropdown;

public void ClickDropdown() throws InterruptedException {       
    getVisibleElement(dropdown)).click();

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. Now I just have to decide whether it's worth going back and changing all my POMs with if statements :/

Comment: This is not the best implementation. SiKing's is actually better and more flexible. This one assumes there will always be 2 elements.

Comment: @JeffC that's what my comments were referring to, I just just didn't want to take the time to go through that implementation detail. The purpose of this answer was to show how you could put this somewhere since it sounds like the OP will have this issue everywhere in the code. Since the exact implementation wasn't the main point, I marked the dangerous parts that should be fixed in the comments

Comment: SiKIng's answer was already a function, I don't understand the purpose of this answer that was less effective than his.

Comment: @JeffC `CustomExpectedConditions` isn't an existing function from what I understand, am I missing something? Anyway, I think you're right I need to update this answer to implement the safer way. If I get some time today I'll do that.

Comment: Maybe it's worth adding some more clarity to my reasoning here. `presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy` won't check if an element is visible, and requires a `By` object. Which is why I felt like it would be useful to add an answer that works with elements, and deals with the OP's specific question, which was a way to get the element that is visible in a way that could be easily used everywhere.

Comment: You can't use `ExpectedConditions` to verify a list of elements will be visible when some of them are and some aren't. That's why SiKing checked for presence, to make sure they were on the page, and then checked `isDisplayed()` on each to find the one that is visible.

Answer (score 6):

Your assumption "... ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(WebElement) would find the first element visible." is wrong! You will need to declare your WebElement as a List, find all of them, and pick the one that is visible. Here is a sample that I used successfully in the past:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@ng-model='loginData.username']")
private List<WebElement> txtUsername;

public String getUsername() {
    driverWait.until(CustomExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElements(txtUsername));
    for (WebElement oneUsername : txtUsername) {
        if (oneUsername.isDisplayed())
            return oneUsername.getAttribute("value");
    }
    return null;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    driverWait.until(CustomExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElements(txtUsername));
    for (WebElement oneUsername : txtUsername) {
        if (oneUsername.isDisplayed()) {
            oneUsername.clear();
            oneUsername.sendKeys(username);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Based on discussion elsewhere, here is the CustomExpectedConditions:

```
public class CustomExpectedConditions {
    /**
     * Based on {@link ExpectedConditions#presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(org.openqa.selenium.By)}.
     * 
     * @param elements
     * @return
     */
    public static ExpectedCondition<List<WebElement>> presenceOfAllElements(
            final List<WebElement> elements) {
        return new ExpectedCondition<List<WebElement>>() {

            @Override
            public List<WebElement> apply(WebDriver driver) {
                // List<WebElement> elements = findElements(locator, driver);
                return elements.size() > 0 ? elements : null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know in `Java` you can combine multiple conditions with [`ExpectedConditions.and()`](http://javadox.com/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support/2.53.0/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#and-org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition...-) as below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(
      ExpectedConditions.and(
           ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//selector-dropdown/p)[1]"))),
           ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//selector-dropdown/p)[2]" )))
      )
  );
```

or just try

```
ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//selector-dropdown/p"));
```

to wait until all elements matched by specified selector became visible

Comment: This is waiting for both elements to become visible, when it will only ever be one of them. whether it is opened in mobile or desktop is determined in the @BeforeTest method. So this code does not know which of the elements will be visible. It just needs to find the first one that IS visible.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try `ExpectedConditions.or` instead of `ExpectedConditions.and`

Comment: If this was worked into some kind of a base method to determine which one was visible and return that element, that would make it easier to use everywhere without having if statments all over the place.

Comment: Not sure why this got down voted, the `EpectedConditions.or` is hugely useful for this question, which is why I upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Also try to look for atribute in DOM, which makes the element visible. That's the fastes and should be prefered aproach.

For example your element in DOM might be or sit under element with 'display: none;' or 'position: fixed'
Then your x-path might for example look like:

```
//div[not(contains(@style,'display: none;')) ...
```

or

```
//div[contains(@style,'position: fixed') ...
```

Or there might be something else.

**DOM by it self always tells you which element is visible and which is not.**

Answer (score -1):

This is the method I came up with, maybe someone can use the full solution. This will A. wait for the first element in a list to be visible, then B. assign the visible one as a single element. The wait is short because it shouldn't take more than a second to figure out which element is visible.

```
    protected WebElement getVisibleElement(List<WebElement> elements) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 1);
    WebElement rE = null;
    int elementsSize = elements.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < elementsSize; i++) {
        System.out.println("test" + i);
        try {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.or(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(elements.get(i))));
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //handle exception however you like
        }
    }
    for (WebElement element : elements) {
        if (element.isDisplayed()) {
            System.out.println("found and assigning to rE");
            rE = element;
            break;
        }
    }
    return rE;
}
```